# Changing .gif on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, gif, attr

I have a menu that contains an animated logo link at the center and 2 spans inside.

When the mouse is over the div ".menu", the .gif changes at the beginning.
Then on *mouseout* the same div's image changes again.

But I have a problem :
What I want is when a user places the cursor on ".menu", the gif changes for each menu item as well, at the beginning of the parent link on the menu.

I don't want that the .gif to change within the menu!

**[DEMO IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kYTkj/7/)**

```
$(".menu")
.mouseover(function() {   
    $(".logo img").attr("src", "http://www.makingdifferent.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/123.gif");  
});

$(".menu").mouseout(function() {   
    $(".logo img").attr("src", "http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rrrrroll01.gif");  
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML? The mouseout is correct, you just have to put it on a different element probably.

Comment: You can see the HTML at the DEMO IN FIDDLE link that I posted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `.mouseover` to `.mouseenter`, and change `.mouseout` to `.mouseleave`.

check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYTkj/13/)

```
$(".menu")
.mouseenter(function() {   
    $(".logo img").attr("src", "http://www.makingdifferent.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/123.gif");  
});

$(".menu").mouseleave(function() {   
    $(".logo img").attr("src", "http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rrrrroll01.gif");  
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use jQuery for this.

When you can use css, use it! :]

Here is the changes I made and I believe this is what you want,

HTML:

```
<span class="logo"><a class="gif" href="#"></a></span>
```

CSS:

```
.gif {
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url("http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rrrrroll01.gif");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: block;
}

.menu:hover .gif {
    background-image: url("http://www.makingdifferent.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/123.gif");    
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYTkj/10/)

Comment: Yes, but I want the gif restart from the beginning.

Comment: If you need this then refer to any of the other answers on your question, here is a fiddle I made with `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` : http://jsfiddle.net/kYTkj/12/.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events:

```
$(".menu").mouseenter(function() {   
    $(".logo img").prop("src", "http://www.makingdifferent.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/123.gif");  
}).mouseleave(function() {   
    $(".logo img").prop("src", "http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rrrrroll01.gif");  
});
```

From the jQuery documentation:

> The `mouseleave` event differs from `mouseout` in the way it handles event bubbling. ... The `mouseleave` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant.
>
> `mouseout` fires when the pointer moves out of child element as well, while `mouseleave` fires only when the pointer moves out of the bound element.